# How to compare Sharepoint List Items Values?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

[image]

Dear All,

My list constains date/time items and I want to get the biggest value of dates. For my example, 1 May 2012 nearest day for today? how can I compare these values and get latest one with C#? I accessed the list and Items in code;

```
using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb)
{
      SPList alertList = web.Lists["Alert Status"];
      if (alertList != null)
      {
          foreach (SPListItem alertItem in alertList.Items)
          {
              DateTime startDate = (DateTime)alertItem["Alert Date"];

          }
      }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get the latest one or the closest date from today (including dates in the past)?

Comment: I want to get the closest date from today. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend to retrieve and sort the items with a [CAML query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521.aspx). You can use the [SPQuery Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.aspx):

```
SPList list = web.Lists["Alert Status"];

SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = @"<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Alert_x0020_Date' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy>";
query.RowLimit = 1;

SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
return items.Count == 0 ? DateTime.MinValue : (DateTime) items[0]["Alert Date"];
```

If there are a lot items in your list, `SPList.Items` is very slow since all items are fetched from the database.

**Update:**

You should not dispose `SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb`. It may be referenced later by other code. Use the rule *only dispose objects you are opening yourself* as guideline.
See [Disposing Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557362.aspx) for more information.

Comment: +1 for explaining the right way of disposing SPWeb Object. Your answer would have been even better if you had suggested LINQ to SharePoint to OP. I can't think of going back to writing CAML string :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you collect your dates like this:

```
List<DateTime> dates;
using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb)
{
  SPList alertList = web.Lists["Alert Status"];
  if (alertList != null)
  {
      dates = alertList.Items.Select(alertItem => (DateTime)alertItem["Alert Date"]).ToList();
  }
}
```

This will give you the latest absolute date:

`dates.OrderByDescending(date => date).First();`

This will give you the date *closest to right now*:

`dates.OrderBy(date => Math.Abs((date - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds)).First();`